# Custom listener in ExpandableListView adapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am extending `BaseExpandableListAdapter` adapter to populate the data in `ExpandableListView`. I have tried to implement a custom listener with which I would like to notify this adapter from my parent class.

I have implemented listener like this:

```
public interface MyListener {
    public void onNext();
}
```

Then I am using this in parent class like this:

```
ExpandableListView lv = new ExpandableListView(this.getContext());
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
MyListener adapterListener = (MyListener) lv.getExpandableListAdapter();

adapterListener.onNext();
```

and I am using this inside extended adapter like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements MyListener {


    @Override
    public void onNext() {

    }
}
```

But this is not catching the event in my custom adapter class. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notify the Adapter then in your Adapter class in your constructor

```
MyListener adapterListener;
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyListener adapterListener)
{    
this.adapterListener = adapterListener    
}
```

and call the method in the adapter where you want to handle the event
adapterListener.onNext();

and then in you Activity or fragment class just implement the interface.